# How does one divide two Nats in Coq?

Tags: coq

I wanted to divide two numbers in Coq because I was trying to implement my own custom `Imp` language and had a statement:

```
    match (aeval st a1) with
      | Some n0 => Some (NDiv n0 (S n))
      | None => None
```

however `/` returns an error:

```
Unknown interpretation for notation "_ / _".
```

and so does `NDiv`, error:

```
The reference NDiv was not found in the current environment.
```

what can I do so that I don't get this error?

How does one do something like the python "integer division" but with nats?

Comment: cross posted: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-does-one-divide-two-Nats-in-Coq

Comment: Seems like:

    `Require Import Coq.Init.Nat.`

works, but I wonder how I could have searched this more efficiently without having to resort to put this trivial Q on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the command `Require Import Arith.` which will import, among other things, the function `Nat.div` and the notation `_ / _` for it.

Comment: `Require Import Coq.Init.Nat.` seems to also work. How could I have search this trivial thing by myself? I tried to google integer division or nat division and variants but got no luck...

Comment: You can browse the standard library https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/ The reference manual also has a chapter giving a quick overview of the core components https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/coq-library.html

Answer (score 1):

Seems like:

```
Require Import Coq.Init.Nat.
```

works, but I wonder how I could have searched this more efficiently without having to resort to put this trivial Q on SO.